# Unexpected Number error

Tags: javascript, html

I have been writing a function to allow users to upload images from their local file system to a website using JavaScript. I have successfully been able to upload images to the browser.

I have also written a function to allow the user to delete these images.

```
var count = 0;
function getPhoto(){

    var file = document.getElementById('ad_photo');
    var list = document.getElementById('ad_photo_upload');
    var fReader = new FileReader();
    var photo_list = [];
    var counter;

    fReader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
    fReader.onloadend = function(event){

        counter = count.toString();

        list.innerHTML += "<li id = 'pic " + counter + "'><img src='" + event.target.result + "'></img><a class = 'close' onclick = 'rem_pic(pic " + counter + ")'>X</a></li>"; 
        photo_list[count] = event.target.result;
        count++;

    }



}

function rem_pic(theID){

    var element = document.getElementById(theID);
    element.outerHTML = "";
    delete element;

}
```

My issue is whenever I call the "rem_pic(theID)" function I get a Chrome Browser error message that says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number". Does anyone have any clue to why this might be? And how I could possibly improve the functions I have written so they work correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because you pass a number to your function:

```
'rem_pic(pic " + counter + ")'
```

will render to

```
'rem_pic(pic 1)'
             ^ or any other number according to your counter value
```

And this is wrong as javascript params can't contain spaces.

So you probably need to pass a string:

```
rem_pic(\"pic " + counter + "\")
```

Looking at your code seems like you use it's as HTML `id` attribute. `id` attribute can't contain space chars too so your code should be like

```
rem_pic(\"pic" + counter + "\")
```

if your `id` in layout has format `id="pic1"`, `id="pic2"`, etc.